# Можно ли использовать веб-метод suggest напрямую, в обход JsApi?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Хотим использовать у себя на проекте функционал [suggest](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/suggest.html)

Собрали минимальный пример - загрузилось 700kb скриптов. Кажется это перебор если нам нужно только дергать один метод апи https://suggest-maps.yandex.ru/suggest-geo

Вопрос: насколько безопасно напрямую вызывать метод https://suggest-maps.yandex.ru/suggest-geo?v=5&search_type=tp&part=%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%89&lang=ru_RU&n=5? Как работает его версионирование и обратная совместимость?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=ваш API-ключ&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ymaps.ready(() => ymaps.suggest('мыт').then(console.log));
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Яндекс не поддерживает и не гарантирует работу внутренних методов (коим несомненно является прямой вызов саджеста). Эти методы могут быть в любой момент изменены.

Более того, использование недокументированных возможностей это нарушение условий использования API Яндекс.Карт, а точнее [Пользовательского соглашения](https://yandex.ru/legal/maps_api/), пункта 2.3.4:
*Пользователь может использовать Данные, функции и инструменты, полученные при помощи Сервиса, только в рамках функциональности, предоставляемой Сервисом.*

А раз необходимость отображения результата на карте Яндекс всё равно требует загрузки JS API, значит скрипт всё равно будет нужен.

Кроме того Яндекс отказался от модульной системы загрузки кода в пользу статических бандлов кода с вечным кэшированием. Потому код API у большинства пользователей (ввиду множества сайтов с картой Яндекса) уже давно кэширован и не требует дополнительной загрузки. А значит временем и трафиком на загрузку этих 700 килобайт можно в значительной мере пренебречь.